# Box2D - Character sticking to sides of objects

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am using Box2D with libgdx. I am having an issue with the default collision action. When I jump or hit the top of an object, everything works fine. My object doesn't stick. If it hits the top, it stands on it. If it hits the bottom, it falls back down. But if it hits either of the sides, my object sticks, as long as I'm moving in that direction. In other words, the gravity has no effect on it while it collides with the side of the block/wall. I did some research, but all solutions said to use the b2Settings, which I can't use with libgdx. Is there any way I can fix this? The code I use to move my character(moving left) is as follows:

```
level.character.body.setLinearVelocity(
                        -level.character.terminalVelocity.x,
                        level.character.body.getLinearVelocity().y);
```

Here's an illustration. As you can see, it sticks to the brick instead of falling. (My character is currently a coin :p)

[image: Sticking to the wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SetLinearVelocity, try using ApplyForce or ApplyImpulse to move things around. The problem is that SetLinearVelocity allows you to create unrealistic situations, for example in this case when the ball hits the wall it should stop and the horizontal velocity really should be zero, but you are overriding the natural result and saying that the ball did not stop at all, and it is still moving.

Note that you may still get this problem even when using ApplyForce or ApplyImpulse, if the force is strong enough and there is enough friction between the fixtures (just like in the real world, if you push something against a wall hard enough and the surfaces are not too slippery, you can stop it from falling).

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I'll rewrite the input for movement and let you know how it worked out. :)